# apt --fix-broken install error

Tags: apt

```
(Reading database ... 173946 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack .../gimp-data_2.10.12+om-1ubu18.04.1~ppa_all.deb ...
Unpacking gimp-data (2.10.12+om-1ubu18.04.1~ppa) ...
dpkg: error processing archive /var/cache/apt/archives/gimp-data_2.10.12+om-1ubu18.04.1~ppa_all.deb (--unpack):
 unable to open '/usr/share/locale/br/LC_MESSAGES/gimp20-std-plug-ins.mo.dpkg-new': Operation not permitted
Errors were encountered while processing:
 /var/cache/apt/archives/gimp-data_2.10.12+om-1ubu18.04.1~ppa_all.deb
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)


/etc/apt/sources.list:deb us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ bionic main restricted
/etc/apt/sources.list:deb us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ bionic-updates main restricted
/etc/apt/sources.list:deb us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ bionic universe
/etc/apt/sources.list:deb us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ bionic-updates universe
/etc/apt/sources.list:deb us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ bionic multiverse
/etc/apt/sources.list:deb us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ bionic-updates multiverse
/etc/apt/sources.list:deb us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ bionic-backports main restricted universe multiverse
/etc/apt/sources.list:deb security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-security main restricted
/etc/apt/sources.list:deb security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-security universe
/etc/apt/sources.list:deb security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-security multiverse
/etc/apt/sources.list.d/otto-kesselgulasch-ubuntu-gimp-bionic.list:deb ppa.launchpad.net/otto-kesselgulasch/gimp/ubuntu bionic main
/etc/apt/sources.list.d/kritalime-ubuntu-ppa-bionic.list.save:deb ppa.launchpad.net/kritalime/ppa/ubuntu bionic main
/etc/apt/sources.list.d/uget-team-ubuntu-ppa-bionic.list.save:deb ppa.launchpad.net/uget-team/ppa/ubuntu bionic main
/etc/apt/sources.list.d/plushuang-tw-ubuntu-uget-stable-bionic.list.save:deb http://ppa.launchpad.net/plushuang-tw/uget-stable/ubuntu bionic main
/etc/apt/sources.list.d/uget-team-ubuntu-ppa-bionic.list:deb ppa.launchpad.net/uget-team/ppa/ubuntu bionic main
/etc/apt/sources.list.d/enpass.list.save:deb https://apt.enpass.io/ stable main
/etc/apt/sources.list.d/otto-kesselgulasch-ubuntu-gimp-bionic.list.save:deb http://ppa.launchpad.net/otto-kesselgulasch/gimp/ubuntu bionic main
/etc/apt/sources.list.d/enpass.list:deb https://apt.enpass.io/ stable main
/etc/apt/sources.list.d/kritalime-ubuntu-ppa-bionic.list:deb http://ppa.launchpad.net/kritalime/ppa/ubuntu bionic main
/etc/apt/sources.list.d/philip5-ubuntu-extra-bionic.list:deb http://ppa.launchpad.net/philip5/extra/ubuntu bionic main
/etc/apt/sources.list.d/plushuang-tw-ubuntu-uget-stable-bionic.list:deb http://ppa.launchpad.net/plushuang-tw/uget-stable/ubuntu bionic main
```

Comment: try deleting all the conetent   by using  rm -rf /var/cache/apt/archives/*

Comment: Deleting the entire package cache seems a bit harsh. The error is "operation not permitted" for one package. Re-download that one package.

Comment: can you show your active package-sources? `grep -P -r '^[ \t]*[^#[ \t]+'  /etc/apt/sources.list /etc/apt/sources.list.d`  I think gimp is from [link] (https://launchpad.net/~otto-kesselgulasch/+archive/ubuntu/gimp)

Comment: Hey thanks for the responses, you guys are alot smarter than me i'm a ubuntu beginner. Here is the out put.

Comment: i edited the original post with that output because it was to long to post in comments